# excel vba object required error when copying from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know why:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(url)
Worksheets("MF All In Rates").Range("C8:P8").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Dashboard_Final.xlsm").Worksheets("HIST COF").Range(Cells(Current.Row, 4), Cells(Current.Row, 17))
```

would give me an object required error? the url is valid and MF All In Rates is a valid sheet in the opened spreadsheet. Do I have to give a more specific filepath than Dashboard_Final.xlsm even though the macro is in that work book??

Comment: I assume wb and url have been declared above.  Include your declarations and variable values when possible.

Comment: Try to break down the concatenated statement to find out which variable is null. You can also type ?<variable_name> in the immediate window to get the current value of the variable. Try putting quotes around "Dashboard_Final.xlsm" - it looks like you're trying to use a string there?

Comment: What is `current`? Also: there should not be parentheses round the `Copy` arguments, and you need to qualify **both** the `Range` and `Cells` calls with the same worksheet.

Comment: Rory, so i can't copy from one worksheet to another?

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to reproduce this (I'm currently on my Linux machine), I think you're missing quotes around "Dashboard_Final.xlsm".

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(url)
wb.Worksheets("MF All In Rates") _ 'did you mean to use the wb var here?
    .Range("C8:P8") _
    .Copy(Destination:= Workbooks("Dashboard_Final.xlsm") _ 'changed this line
        .Worksheets("HIST COF") _
        .Range(Cells(Current.Row, 4), Cells(Current.Row, 17)))
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments to both the answers, I'm guessing you're trying to interact with the workbook you just opened (with `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(url)`). If that's the case, make sure you are using that workbook (using the `wb.Worksheets...` line in my example). Here's one way to test it more coarsely:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(url)

Dim wbDest as Excel.Workbook, rngDest as Excel.Range, wsDest as Excel.Worksheet
Set wbDest = Workbooks("Dashboard_Final.xlsm")
Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("HIST COF")
set rngDest = wsDest.Range(cells(Current.Row, 4), Cells(Current.Row, 17))

wb.Worksheets("MF All In Rates").Range("C8:P8").Copy Destination:= rngDest
```

It's also better to standardise your cell references - either use Range(cells...cells) or Range("C#:C#") - this makes it clearer to see that the ranges are the same size.

If you are still having problems, try writing each cell across individually - something like:

`wsDest.cells(8, 3).value = wsSource.Cells(Current.Row, 4).value`

or

```
Dim Arr() as Variant, rng as Excel.Range

Arr = wsSource.Range("C8:P8") 'put the data in the source sheet into an array

Set rng = wsDest.Range(cells(Current.Row, 4), Cells(Current.Row, 17)) 'get the destination range

rng.Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr 'resize the range (just in case) and transpose the array to the worksheet
```

where wsDest is the destination worksheet (where you copy to) and wsSource is the source worksheet (where you are copying from). You can find more on transposing ranges to arrays and arrays to ranges [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: i added quotes where you have them and now I'm getting an application-defined or object-defined error; do you know why that might be?

Comment: I would start by breaking down the statement, as Don suggests. Look at where the error is occurring by stepping through the code line by line (you can hit F8 to execute a line), and checking that objects have been correctly assigned. Application defined error has a very broad meaning - it's probably that you are violating the rules of Excel in some way, but without seeing the workbook, it's difficult to say.

Comment: i tried that and all of the lines are able to execute; does that mean i'm doing the copy function wrong? and thank you for your help!

Comment: @ajs I've updated my answer to provide some other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For troubleshooting long references like this, break them down into individual lines and step through it. If you write your code like this, you will be able to fairly easily determine where the error is:

```
Dim oBook As WorkBook
Dim oSheet As WorkSheet
Dim oRange As Range
Dim vCell1 As Variant
Dim vCell2 As Variant

vCell1 = Cells(Current.Row, 4)
vCell2 = Cells(Current.Row, 17)

Set oBook = Workbooks(Dashboard_Final.xlsm)
Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("HIST COF")
Set oRange = oSheet.Range(vCell1, vCell2)
```

Comment: all of these lines of testing code are able to execute when i run them and the url i tell to open opens a spreadsheet so i don't understand what the problem could be

Comment: So if this code works, continue to use it to flesh out the routine you are trying to create rather than a single line of references strung together.  You should be able to isolate your error to a single method call or object reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212582/copy-range-from-one-sheet-to-another-vba